# New to C++, modules and switch menu

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on a project that involves creating a menu screen, and integrating three programs into one that can be selectively launched from the menu screen.

I thought making individual programs first before piecing them together with switch case and functions would be easy (I don't know class/objects). I keep running into a brick wall and a host of syntax/logical errors, so I deleted everything and now I'm back to square one-- with three distinct programs. This is very daunting-- how do  proceed? :/

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int x;
  cout << "Enter the amount of money you have ";
  cin >> x;
  if (x >= 20) {
    cout << "You can buy Comic Book $1 or Sports Journal $3 or Science Book $15 or Third Volume Series $20";
  } else if (x >= 15 && x < 20) {
    cout << "You can buy Comic Book $1 or Sports Journal $3 or Science book $15";
  } else if (x >= 3 && x < 15) {
    cout << "You can buy Comic Book $1 or Sports Journal $3";
  } else if (x >= 1 && x < 3) {
    cout << "You can buy Comic Book $1";
  } else if (x <= 0) {
    cout << "You cannot afford anything";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int numclass; //number of classes
  int numStudents; //number of students
  int numTests; // Number of tests per student
  double sectiontotal; //Accumulator for Class total scores
  double total; // Accumulator for total scores
  double average; //Average test score
  double totalaverage = 0;
  ofstream outfile;
  outfile.open("Gradesinfo.txt");
  // Set up numeric output formatting.
  cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);

  // Get the number of students.
  cout << "This program gives average of test scores per student, per class, and for the whole institution for upto 2 students in upto 2 different classes in 3 subjects\n";

  //  Determine each student's average score.
  cout << "Enter the number of classes";
  cin >> numclass;
  cout << "Enter the number of students per class";
  cin >> numStudents;
  cout << "Enter the number of tests";
  cin >> numTests;
  for (int section = 1; section <= numclass; section++) {
    sectiontotal = 0; //Initialize class accumulator
    totalaverage = 0;
    for (int student = 1; student <= numStudents; student++) {
      total = 0; // Initialize the accumulator.
      for (int test = 1; test <= numTests; test++) {
        double score;
        cout << "Enter score " << test << " for ";
        cout << "student " << student << ": ";
        cin >> score;
        if (score >= 0 && score <= 100) {
          total += score;
        } else {
          cout << "Enter value from 1 - 100" << endl;
          test = test - 1;
        }
      }
      average = total / numTests;
      totalaverage += average;
      cout << "The average score for student " << student;
      cout << " is " << average << ".\n\n";
      outfile << "The average score for student " << student;
      outfile << " is " << average << ".\n\n";
    }
    cout << "The total average for class " << section << " is: " << totalaverage / numStudents << endl;
    outfile << "The total average for class " << section << " is: " << totalaverage / numStudents << endl;
    sectiontotal += totalaverage;
  }
  cout << "The total average for the institution is: " << sectiontotal / numclass;
  outfile << "The total average for the institution is: " << sectiontotal / numclass;
  outfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  fstream instream;
  ofstream outstream;
  instream.open("Grades.txt");
  if (instream.fail()) {
    cout << "The input file failed to open\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  int next, largest, smallest;
  largest = 0;
  smallest = 0;    

  while (instream >> next) {

    if (largest < next) {
      largest = next;
    } else {
      smallest = next;
    }
  }

  cout << "The highest grade is: " << largest << endl;
  instream.close();
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1st things is: you can not have more than 1 entry point or main method to the application, so pick one file as a main entrance and clear the rest,

Comment: please fix the indentation. and the `x < 15`, `x < 3`... in the `else` part is redundant because they're always true at that time

Answer (score 1):

I think you are shooting yourself on the foot. go 1 step after the other, please do take this as reference:

1. create a main file as entry point for the app, note the prototype and implementation of the functions **printA** and **printB**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printA();
void printB();

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    cout << "Enter the option:\n";
    while (cin >> x)
    {
        if (x <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        switch (x) {
        case 1:
            printA();
            break;
        case 2:
            printB();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


void printB()
{
    cout << "B";
}

void printA()
{
    cout << "A";
}
```

2. create a new file fooA.cpp and paste there the implemented function printA
3. do the same for the printB in another file.
4. remove those implementations from main.cpp

you are done!

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks a lot.